# Show $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ax \sin bx}{x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi a}{2} $ if $ a < b$

Tags: improper-integrals

Show that if $a < b$:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ax \sin bx}{x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi a}{2} $$

I could see solution by Fourier analysis or by Contour Integration, but why does the larger frequency $b$ not matter?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to this very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769766/complex-how-to-approach-improper-integral/1769860

Comment: The reason is essentially that $\mathbb{1}_{(-a,a)}(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(-b,b)}(x) = \mathbb{1}_{(-\min(a,b),\min(a,b))}(x)$ if $a,b>0$.

Comment: my question is a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441106/how-do-i-show-that-int-0-infty-sinax-sinbx-x2-pi-mina-b-2?rq=1